# use stat_compare_means with own p.signif labels

Tags: r, ggpubr

I am struggling with a plot using `ggplot2` and `ggpubr` together and I guess on one side it is a font issue. On the other side, a more general solution would be to use own user defined labels...

When I use the `stat_compare_means` function, everything is fine except the asterisk are not entered but superscript, which is in general a font setting. I would like to replace the `*` by a unicode string with a centred asterisk but to get there, I need to provide the data by hand to the `stat_compare_means` function. I tried this by just using the `compare_means` function output and wanted to update the `p.signif` column with my personal preferred labelling... But this doesn't work at all and I don't understand the error message at that point. How does the data needs to be provided if I want to overwrite the `p.signif` strings?

```
df <- data.frame(
  name = rep(letters[1:5], each=4), 
  value = c(25.93, 25.77, 25.97, 26.26, 26.44, 26.24, 26.23, 26.35, 26.14, 
            26.21, 26.38, 26.29, 25.83, 25.69, 25.76, 25.59, 26.23, 26.3, 
            26.4, 26.49))


ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y=value, color=name)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) +
  geom_point(color='black', position=position_jitter(width=.15), alpha=.4) +
  # stat_compare_means(ref.group='e', label = "p.signif", method='t.test')  
  stat_compare_means(data=compare_means(value ~ name, data=df, method='t.test', ref.group='e'),
                     label = "p.signif")
```

By uncommenting the line, the plot is nice, except the asterisks, I want to change them to a different string.

**EDIT**

So I am getting closer to a solution, since now I figured, the `label=psignif` is not a column name but a setting in the function it self, I studied the description of the function a bit closer. I found the `symnum.args` argument which is supposed to overwrite the preferred labels. Exactly what I am looking for, but for some reason it can not handle my asterisk unicode characters ([I tested some of those](https://unicode-suche.de/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=ASTERISK)) ... By testing with a greek letter it worked. Just the centered asterisk is not shown. Anyone an idea?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y=value, color=name)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) +
  geom_point(color='black', position=position_jitter(width=.15), alpha=.4) +
  # stat_compare_means(ref.group='e', label = "p.signif", method='t.test')  
  # stat_compare_means(data=compare_means(value ~ name, data=df, method='t.test', ref.group='e'),
  #                    label = "p.signif") 
  stat_compare_means(ref.group='e', label = "p.signif", method='t.test', 
                     symnum.args=list(
                       cutpoints = c(0, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 1), 
                       # symbols = c("\u2217\u2217\u2217\u2217", "\u2217\u2217\u2217", "\u2217\u2217", "\u2217", "ns")))
                       # symbols = c("****", "***", "**", "*", "ns")))
                       symbols = c("\u00B5\u00B5\u00B5\u00B5", "\u00B5\u00B5\u00B5", "\u00B5\u00B5", "\u00B5", "ns")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get your code working by setting stat_compare_means font `family='mono'`, i.e.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=name, y=value, color=name)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA) +
  geom_point(color='black', position=position_jitter(width=.15), alpha=.4) +
  stat_compare_means(ref.group='e', label = "p.signif", method='t.test', 
                     symnum.args=list(
                       cutpoints = c(0, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 1), 
                       symbols = c("\u2217\u2217\u2217\u2217", "\u2217\u2217\u2217", "\u2217\u2217", "\u2217", "ns")),
                       family='mono')
ggsave('test.pdf', width=11.69, height=8.27, device=cairo_pdf)
```

Setting `family='sans'` or `family='serif'` resulted in empty boxes. Maybe you can play around with your font settings to get to the desired result.

[image]

Comment: I was so sure that I tested the asterisk specific unicode before to make sure it is not a font issue but something related to `ggpubr`, but 5 minutes ago I discovered, it is a font setting and was about to develop a solution to this, then your answer popped up... Thanks, that did the trick!

Comment: for sure, `ggsave` made problems afterwards. So if you want to add, `ggsave('test.pdf', width=11.69, height=8.27, device=cairo_pdf)` setting `device` to `cairo_pdf` let me even save the special character in a pdf file.

Comment: maybe `useDingbats=FALSE` to open it in illustrator afterwards... Always the sam `sh...t`...